# How do I move String values from an array to a tuple without copying?

Tags: arrays, rust, tuples

I have a fixed size array of `String`s: `[String; 2]`. I want to turn it into a `(String, String)`. Can I do this without copying the values?

The piece of code that I'm working on in particular is the following:

```
let (basis, names_0, names_1) = if let Some(names) = self.arg_name {
    (ComparisonBasis::Name, names[0], names[1])
} else {
    (ComparisonBasis::File, self.arg_file[0], self.arg_file[1])
};
```

types:

```
self.arg_name: Option<[String; 2]>
self.arg_file: Vec<String>
```

Right now I'm getting errors

```
cannot move out of type `[std::string::String; 2]`, a non-copy fixed-size array [E0508]
```

and

```
cannot move out of indexed content [E0507]
```

for the two arms of the `if`

Comment: In the end, I guess it's a bit overzealous of me to try to optimise out the calls to clone. The piece of code in the question is called exactly once per program run and it's just two (probably small) strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've omitted a fair amount of context, so I'm taking a guess at a few aspects.  I'm also hewing a little closer to the question you *asked*, rather than the vaguer one implied by your snippets.

```rust
struct NeverSpecified {
    arg_names: Option<[String; 2]>,
    arg_file: Vec<String>,
}

impl NeverSpecified {
    fn some_method_i_guess(mut self) -> (String, String) {
        if let Some(mut names) = self.arg_names {
            use std::mem::replace;
            let name_0 = replace(&mut names[0], String::new());
            let name_1 = replace(&mut names[1], String::new());
            (name_0, name_1)
        } else {
            let mut names = self.arg_file.drain(0..2);
            let name_0 = names.next().expect("expected 2 names, got 0");
            let name_1 = names.next().expect("expected 2 names, got 1");
            (name_0, name_1)
        }
    }
}
```

I use [`std::mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) to switch the contents of the array, whilst leaving it in a valid state.  This is necessary because Rust won't allow you to have a "partially valid" array.  There are no copies or allocations involved in this path.

In the other path, we have to pull elements out of the vector by hand.  Again, you can't just move values out of a container via indexing (this is actually a limitation of indexing overall).  Instead, I use [`Vec::drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain) to essentially chop the first two elements out of the vector, then extract them from the resulting iterator.  To be clear: this path doesn't involve any copies or allocations, *either*.

As an aside, those `expect` methods *shouldn't* ever be triggered (since `drain` does bounds checking), but better paranoid than sorry; if you want to replace them with `unwrap()` calls instead, that should be fine..

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :) Sorry for the vagueness in the question.

Comment: @Apanatshka: Just to be clear, neither branch in the example involves copying or allocating; it's *purely* moves (and empty values in the first branch).  Just wanted to clarify since your comment on your question could imply you think there's no way to do this without copying.

Comment: I understand that your example doesn't do any copying (but it does allocate new (empty) `String`s right?). I just decided that in this case a call to `clone` is fine, and slightly less effort to write and read :)

Comment: @Apanatshka it creates empty strings, but doing so does *not* involve any actual allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Since Rust 1.36, you can use *slice patterns* to bind to all the values of the array at once:

```
struct NeverSpecified {
    arg_names: Option<[String; 2]>,
    arg_file: Vec<String>,
}

impl NeverSpecified {
    fn some_method_i_guess(mut self) -> (String, String) {
        if let Some([name_0, name_1]) = self.arg_names.take() {
            (name_0, name_1)
        } else {
            let mut names = self.arg_file.drain(0..2);
            let name_0 = names.next().expect("expected 2 names, got 0");
            let name_1 = names.next().expect("expected 2 names, got 1");
            (name_0, name_1)
        }
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Method for safely moving all elements out of a generic array into a tuple with minimal overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49348654/155423)